# Google Chrome Developer Tools: search for exact match

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-tools

How can I search for some text that has spaces in it in all JavaScript sources on website?
I know that I should use "CTRL + SHIFT + F"(on Windows), but Google Chrome Developer Tools searches not for the whole sentence, but for each word that is separated by space.
How to find exactly what I've typed into searchbox ?

Please see screenshot:
[image: How search works]

Is it a bug in Chrome version "33.0.1750.117" ? It worked ok previously... Is there a workaround?

Comment: That's weird, mine works as expected, I'm on 33.0.1750.117 too.

Comment: I'm on the same version but it didn't work. I had to use Regex and search for `Get\ all` to get what I wanted. In the results I'm seeing `Get all` (with space) highlighted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use double quotes to search for the whole sentence:

```
ex. "Get all"
```

Comment: Where were you earlier ? :)
It does work, thank you! Accepted answer.

Strange behavior, why should I every time put double quotes, seems user unfriendly.